# Use variable instead of data table column name reference in sum

Tags: r, variables, sum, names

I have a table (Table1) with over 200 columns and thousands of rows with numeric data, most of which are months, and the column names are of the format 'Jan 2018', 'Feb 2018' etc.

```
report[1,2] <- sum(Table1$`Mar 2018`[which(Table1$`Product`=="Apples")])
```

Instead of using 'Mar 2018', I would like to replace that somehow with a variable name (let's call it searchMonth).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `[[` to do this

```
searchMonth <- "Mar 2018"
sum(Table1[[searchMonth]][Table1$Product=="Apples"])
```

Backquotes or quotes are only needed when there are spaces or special characters in the column names.  Otherwise, it can be simply extracted without quoting

Comment: @akrun Is there a specific reason to prefer `[[` over `[` in this case?

Comment: @doviod  The `[[` extract column as a vector, while `[`, it is still a list or data.frame with one column. and `sum` works on `vector`s instead of `data.frame`.  You can check this by `class(Table[searchMonth])` and `class(Table[[searchMonth]])`

Comment: @akrun oh, I did not know that. Thanks!